# JSON response through loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, loops

I am using ajax to fetch a string from a PHP script. The string is in the format of a JSON array consisting of multiple objects.

I can successfully access the objects, but I have no luck when using a loop. I need to access the objects in reverse order.

AJAX STRING RESPONSE:

```
{
  "messages": [{
      "username": "John",
      "message": "Hello!",
      "age": 32,
    },
    {
      "username": "Bob",
      "message": "Awesome day",
      "age": 26,
    },
    {
      "username": "Sarah",
      "message": "How are you?",
      "age": 19,
    }
  ]
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var messageList = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);

var message_count = messageList.messages.length;

while (message_count >= 0) {
    alert(messageList.messages[message_count].username);
    message_count -= 1;
}
```

I basically need the alerts to be in the order: Sarah Bob John
I can access the array when I do something like:
    alert(messageList.messages[0].username);

It only seems to fail when I use the message_count variable. I have searched many hours for similar problems but found no success.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array has length 3, but arrays are indexed from zero, so you need to subtract 1 from your length total for the loop to work (`messages[3]` doesn't exist).

```
var message_count = messageList.messages.length - 1;
```

The loop will go from 2 to 0 and give you the correct output.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m4L05b7d/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
    var messages = data.messages || {};
    $.each(messages,function(key,info){
        console.log(info.username);
        console.log(info.message);
        console.log(info.age);
    });
});
```